# jQuery hide div if not with specific ID

Tags: jquery

I got a form that will create duplicates of its self on click.

I want to be able to clear the input fields and hide the specific divs on another click if not the first row. If this is the first div it should only clear the form.

what i got is this:

```
<div id="fields_1" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="items">
    <div class="form_div">
        <input name="01_name" id="01_name" value="" placeholder="name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_div plusminus">
        <div class="minus">
            <span>Delete Row</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="fields_2" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="items">
    <div class="form_div">
        <input name="02_name" id="02_name" value="" placeholder="name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_div plusminus">
        <div class="minus">
            <span>Delete Row</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".minus").click(function(){
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find(':input').val('');
        if($(this).parent('div').parent('div').not('#fields_1'))
        {
            $(this).parent('div').parent('div').hide('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone see were i am wrong?

Comment: Try `if($(this).parent('div').parent('div:not('#fields_1')'))`

Comment: nope that will also break the code for duplicating the form :(

Comment: Then don't duplicate the form with same id

Comment: Use classes.  Add a `class="first"` to the first row.  When you duplicate the row, remove the class `$(this).removeClass("first")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change these three lines:

```
if($(this).parent('div').parent('div').not('#fields_1'))
{
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').hide('slow');
}
```

to be this:

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('div').not('#fields_1').hide('slow');
```

The reason is that `.not` is used to filter a query selection. It does not return `true` or `false`.

So when you execute `$(this).parent('div').parent('div')` you have a selection of `div`s. Now when you run `.not('#fields_1')` on that selection you **remove** any div that **is true** for the test "has id of `fields_1`". Now your selection doesn't contain the `div` with that `id` and you can perform whatever action you want on that filtered group.

Comment: As Krzysztof mentioned, you should use `closest` instead of multiple `parent` calls

Answer (score 1):

Don't use multiple `parent()` functions. Instead, use `closest()`. And, use `:first-of-type` selector.

Maybe this will help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".minus").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div.items').find('input').val('');
        $(this).closest('div.items').not('div.items:fist-of-type').hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you mate cant accept two answers but your post helped too